# How to get the path for a new USB drive

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, usb-drive, paths

Recently I installed a 2TB usb drive on Ubuntu 20.04, and copied some files onto it.  Now I would like to read those files in a Python program, but I can't get the path to the new drive.

The drive is `/dev/sda1`, and it's mounted at `/mnt/ssk2TB`.  I have a USB key with files on it, and its path is `/media/mpxt/A_MEDIA`.  In `/media/mpxt` I also have an entry for the new 2TB drive as `/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192`.

`Lsblk` confirms it:

```
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb
```

Also,

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` said its UUID is:

`6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192`, which matches.

I used that as a path:

```
fname = "/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17-af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192/Test_Data/Audit_Python/Python_Results"

testdata_fname = open(fname, 'rb')
```

I get this error message:

```
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192/Test_Data/Audit_Python/Python_Results`
```

I can `cd /media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192/Test_Data/Audit_Python` and get a listing of files.  So why can't I use that path to open a file?

What do I use as a path for the USB drive described above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know what mpyt is

Comment: @user68186 - yes.  It was a typo; I just edited it.

Comment: I didn't do anything in /etc/fstab or change anything else.  If it can't be mounted in both /mnt and /media at the same time, how is it that I can see the drive in Nautilus, and can freely move files in and out?  If I were to unmount one or the other, what syntax would I use to open a file, my original question.

Comment: Are you saying that if I unmount the mount point at /mnt/ssk2B and keep the one at /media then my Python file open command should work?  If not, what would the correct syntax be to open a data file on the USB drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try the following:

### Step 1: Unmount from `ssk2TB`

Unmount the external drive from the mount point you have created: `/mnt/ssk2TB`. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo unmount /mnt/ssk2TB
```

If the partition was mounted, this command will return nothing. If the partition was not mounted (or was unmounted before) you will see an error message:

```
umount: /mnt/ssk2TB: not mounted
```

Make sure there are no files or folders inside `/mnt/ssk2TB`, after you unmount the partition. If there are files/folders after you unmount the partition `/dev/sda1`, then it means they were put there by mistake when the partition was not mounted.

Delete the folder `ssk2TB` from inside `/mnt/` if you want.

### Step 2: Unmount from GUI and remove the USB

Using the GUI (using either the desktop of the Files/Nautilus app) "Eject" the external drive `/dev/sda1` mounted at the mount point `/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192`.

Wait for the notification that says the drive can be safely removed.

Physically unplug (remove) the USB drive from the computer.

Check if the folder `/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192` still exist and if there are any files inside. If there are files inside this folder, then they were put there by mistake.

Delete the folder `6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192` from `/media/mpxt/`. This folder should not exist if the USB drive is not connected.

### Step 3 Start Again

Insert the USB drive (plug it in). The computer should recognize it and automatically mount it under `/media/<Your Username>`. For example at `/media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192`.

Now you should be able to access the the files and folders inside the USB drive as the user `mpxt`. If you try to access these files as another user, you may get permission denied.

### File name and extension matters (in python)

Ubuntu (Linux, in general) does not care too much about file extensions. You may name a binary file without an extension such as `Python_Results`. Ubuntu does not care.

However, within python it matters. Renaming the file `Python_Results` to `Python_Results.bin` may help.

Note that in Linux file names are case sensitive. So `Python_Results` and `python_results` are two different files.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much.  It's Thanksgiving day and I have to leave now, but I will do these steps tomorrow, and let you know what happens.

Comment: Your first instruction was to unmount /mnt/ssk2T.  It responded with:
umount: /mnt/ssk2TB: not mounted.

Your second instruction is to "Eject" the external drive.  Nautilus doesn't show an Eject option (just unmount), and GNOME Disks shows only a "power off."  I can use Linux eject from the command line, but I'm not clear on whether I should use eject /dev/sda1 followed by udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sda1, as recommended in the second answer here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/eject-usb-drives-eject-command.  

Before I proceed, I wanted to ask you first.

Comment: You may use unmount from nautilus.

Comment: I followed your steps, and it worked as you said, and it mounted itself at /media/mpxt/6e9ee7e7-17-af-4501-94aa-ffe6bb90c192/ as it did last time.  However, when I open a data file from Python, I still get a file not found error.  So I put a ".bin" extension on the file (because it's being opened with "rb") and now it does open and read.  Thanks for your help.  Now the drive is not double-mounted, and the issue is solved.  .